# difference between onClick={() => this.func()} and onClick={this.func} in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner to React and I tried onClick in these two ways. Can anyone explain the difference between these two?

> ***1st way:--   onClick={() => this.func()}***

```
func(){
  alert("Button Clicked");
}

render() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.func()}> Click Me </button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

> ***2nd way:--   onClick={this.func}***

```
func(){
  alert("Button Clicked");
}

render() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.func}> Click Me </button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1st one is used for passing the arguments and using it in function, 2nd one is directly using function without any argument (calling the function.)